# Cache management Power BI Services and Azure Analysis Services cube

Tags: azure, refresh, powerbi, azure-analysis-services

Hello,

I'm publishing a Power BI report with an Azure Analysis Services cube as source. The thing is that when I open it for the first time in PBI Services, all the visuals and measures are loading which is fine. I'm waiting till the end but then if I close the report and come back later, all the measures will load again and it really is a problem for my customers. I know I can schedule a cache refresh but even if I do so, the reports will still refresh every time I open them.

Any idea to solve this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using live connection, switching to imported should speed things up. This means that when getting the data from SSAS, you should select `Import` option:

[image]

When importing data, your report will not work with the "live" data, but with a cached copy. This will speed things up, but you will need to schedule a refresh. However, with SSAS you probably do not work with live data too. Usually there is a nightly ETL, which will refresh the data in your model. So you may want to [schedule a refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-scheduled-refresh) of your dataset at appropriate time, after the refresh of SSAS is completed.

You can read more about Live connection vs. Import [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Power-BI-Live-connection-vs-Import-comparison-and-limitations/ba-p/84377).

Unfortunately, I don't think you can switch this option for existing reports. There is an [idea](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/18556393-support-switching-ssas-connect-model-from-connect) for which you can vote, though. So you may need to re-create your report to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this possibility but I need to work on Live Connection actually.